# what does かは convey?

Tags: particle-は, particle-が

Here's the context: それについて、見てくれる人がどう思うかは、私は、コントロールできないから手放そうと思いました。

Answer (score 3):

It's two separate particles. か and は.

The か denotes a question (見てくれる人がどう思うか）

The は then just indicates the previous sentence is a topic of what's being spoken about.

見てくれる人がどう思うかは、私は、コントロールできない。。。

As in "As for what the onlookers think, I can't control that."